# Count Combinations across groups in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, data-manipulation

My data is set up as

```
df=data.frame(ID=c('A', 'A','A','B','B','C','C','C', 'C', 'C','D', 'E', 'E'),
                    drink_freq = c('Coffee Light', 'Water Heavy', 'Tea Medium',
                                   'Coffee Medium', 'Water Light', 
                                   'Espresso Light', 'Coffee Medium', 'Water Light', 'Soda Light', 'Tea Medium',
                                   'Coffee Heavy',
                                   'Coffee Medium', 'Soda Light'))
```

And what I would like to do is create some sort of contingency table that shows the frequency of combinations of the different segments a user may be a part of. So for example... Soda Light-Coffee Medium and Coffee Medium-Water Light would be a 2 whereas Coffee Light-Water Heavy would be a 1.

I feel like this isn't that difficult but I've had trouble writing code to do this since the users can be a part of a different number of groups.

Comment: You can check `combh` with `table`

Comment: I'm looking up the combn documentation now but I'm not sure I see how to use it with table. Could you elaborate a little more?

Comment: Without the expected output, it is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution, which creates all unique combinations of drinks (i.e order of drinks is taken into account) and counts how many common users they have:

```
df=data.frame(ID=c('A', 'A','A','B','B','C','C','C', 'C', 'C','D', 'E', 'E'),
              drink_freq = c('Coffee Light', 'Water Heavy', 'Tea Medium',
                             'Coffee Medium', 'Water Light', 
                             'Espresso Light', 'Coffee Medium', 'Water Light', 'Soda Light', 'Tea Medium',
                             'Coffee Heavy',
                             'Coffee Medium', 'Soda Light'), stringsAsFactors = F)

library(tidyverse)

data.frame(t(combn(unique(df$drink_freq), 2)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(counts = map2_dbl(X1, X2, ~length(intersect(df$ID[df$drink_freq==.x], 
                                                     df$ID[df$drink_freq==.y]))))

#                X1             X2 counts
# 1    Coffee Light    Water Heavy 1
# 2    Coffee Light     Tea Medium 1
# 3    Coffee Light  Coffee Medium 0
# 4    Coffee Light    Water Light 0
# 5    Coffee Light Espresso Light 0
# 6    Coffee Light     Soda Light 0
# 7    Coffee Light   Coffee Heavy 0
# 8     Water Heavy     Tea Medium 1
# 9     Water Heavy  Coffee Medium 0
# 10    Water Heavy    Water Light 0
# 11    Water Heavy Espresso Light 0
# 12    Water Heavy     Soda Light 0
# 13    Water Heavy   Coffee Heavy 0
# 14     Tea Medium  Coffee Medium 1
# 15     Tea Medium    Water Light 1
# 16     Tea Medium Espresso Light 1
# 17     Tea Medium     Soda Light 1
# 18     Tea Medium   Coffee Heavy 0
# 19  Coffee Medium    Water Light 2
# 20  Coffee Medium Espresso Light 1
# 21  Coffee Medium     Soda Light 2
# 22  Coffee Medium   Coffee Heavy 0
# 23    Water Light Espresso Light 1
# 24    Water Light     Soda Light 1
# 25    Water Light   Coffee Heavy 0
# 26 Espresso Light     Soda Light 1
# 27 Espresso Light   Coffee Heavy 0
# 28     Soda Light   Coffee Heavy 0
```

You can then reshape the above output to a contingency table.

*Note* that if you want to reshape and get a symmetric output you have to modify the above code to ignore the order of the drinks, by creating all possible combinations, like this:

```
expand.grid(X1=unique(df$drink_freq),
            X2=unique(df$drink_freq), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(counts = map2_dbl(X1, X2, ~length(intersect(df$ID[df$drink_freq==.x], 
                                                     df$ID[df$drink_freq==.y])))) %>% 
  filter(X1 != X2)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for! I was thinking I might need to use intersect with length, but using the map2 function was the missing piece. Thanks!

Comment: I do a have a quick question though about the output. If I simply spread it, by adding %>% spread(X2, counts) there are NAs that show up in combinations where there is data. For example, Tea Medium-Coffee Medium has a 1, and shows when Tea Medium is on the vertical axis but not the horizontal axis. Is there a way to fix this? Since it would be nice to look at the percentage splits as well. Thanks again for all the help thus far!

Comment: This is because for the above process the order of the drinks is important. You didn't specified it in your question, but looks like you need a symmetric data frame as an output, right? If that's the case the process needs to be changed.

Comment: Oh ok, yea no the order was completely arbitrary so I was thinking that a symmetric output similar to like a correlation matrix would be sufficient. And then I could append row/column totals and other simple stuff after the fact. But essentially if I store your solution as sol, and then create a new df, sol2 = sol, and then rename the columns names(sol2)[1:2] = c('X2', 'X1') and append this to the sol df, sol = rbind.data.frame(sol, sol2) and then spread it you essentially get the symmetric output. Although i'm sure there's a simpler way